# Tricky Integral Problem with tan and sec function

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Can someone help me evaluate:$$\int \frac{(\sec x)^{2}}{(1+\tan x)^{2}}dx$$
Is it possible for a hint so that I can proceed? I tried changing sec into $ 1 +\tan x $ but did not reach far.

Comment: Is the $^2$ affecting the $x$ of the whole $\sec(x)$? If the latter you can try $y=\tan(x)$.

Comment: The numerator is not $\sec^2 x$?

Comment: It is affecting the whole sec.

Comment: @kobe I edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = \tan x$. Then $du = \sec^2 x\, dx$. Thus

$$\int \frac{\sec^2 x}{(1 + \tan x)^2}\, dx = \int \frac{du}{(1 + u)^2} = \cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

How about modifying this integration into 1/(sinx+cosx)^2 and let sinx+cosx=sqrt2 ×sin (x+pi/4)?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Also, please avoid rhetorical questions unless the context is absolutely clear, for often they look like you're asking a different question entirely.

Comment: @shaun thanks! I will carefully read this material and write clear answer:)